# Is there any visualization tool to see the processing chain (bolt and spouts) in a storm cluster?

Tags: apache-storm

Context:

Seeing a null pointer in one of the integration test, which runs in a locally spawned stom cluster. Increased the log level and could not figure it out what is really happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify - I am looking for Visualization tools to know what is happening in the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't quite match your title.  If you're looking for better access to logs for scalable apps (whether on Hadoop or Storm) then check out tools that collect and aggregate logs from multiple nodes and systems.  I'm familiar with PaperTrail and GreyLog, but I'm sure there are others.  These tools, in conjunction with judicious use of log levels, can help you quickly find errors in your scalable apps.

If you're looking to get a better idea of how your system is performing (this is what I think of when I hear "visualization") then check out distributed monitoring tools.  We've had very good success with the both the visualization of Storm bolt/spout performance and alert processing with CopperEgg, for example.